# Measuring the acceleration due to gravity using an experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, experimental-technique

> *A student measures the acceleration due to gravity, g, using the*
> *apparatus shown in the figure below. A plastic card of known length is*
> *released from rest at a height of $0.50$ metres above a light gate. A computer*
> *calculates the velocity of the card at this point, using the time for*
> *the card to pass through the light gate*
>
> [image]
>
> *State and explain one reason why the card would give more reliable results than a table
> tennis ball for this experiment.*

So my guess is, they want us to somehow argue that the drag force (due to air resistance) experienced by the card will be much less than the ball and thus we will give a more accurate result for the acceleration.

However, I am not sure how to argue this.

Firstly, we haven't been given the dimensions of the card. So we can't determine if the surface area of the card will be greater or less than the table tennis ball.

Secondly, we can't accurately say whether the card or table tennis ball will have higher velocity.

Both velocity and surface area are important components for the value of the drag force. If we can't show that both the velocity and surface area of the card is less than the ball's own velocity and surface area, then we can't say that the card would provide a  more accurate measurement for this experiment.